# Vbscript to find 180days old Logfile from C drive

Tags: vbscript

I have wrote a vbscript to find 180days old log file from C drive. Now the problem in below script is , I am able to get all the log file details from C drive.But not 180days old. Can anyone help me to correct my script please.

```
strComputer = "."
Dim objFile,iDaysOld,item,objFSO,dateTime,Filesize,LargeFile,strCheckDate
Dim FileName,FileName1,Logs,GetFile,file,filemodified,OldFile,LargeFile1
iDaysOld = 180
Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set files = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension='log' AND Drive='C:'")
For Each file in files
If LCase(Right(Cstr(file.Name), 3)) = "log" Then
        FileName1 = Trim(file.Name)
        FileName = (file.Name & "," & FileName)
        Filesize= (file.FileSize)
filemodified = file.lastModified
filemodified = left (filemodified, 8 )
filemodified = Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date)
strCheckDate = strDateCreated
strCheckDate = strDateAccessed
strCheckDate = strDateModified
If strCheckDate < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then
OldFile = (file.Name & "," & OldFile)
End If 
If Filesize >= 104857600 Then
LargeFile = (file.Name & "," & LargeFile)
' oFile.Delete(True) 
    End If 
End If 
Next
wscript.echo "tr_Oldlogfiles=" &OldFile
wscript.echo "tr_Largelogfiles=" &LargeFile
```

Answer (score 1):

[Comparison Operators (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx) article insists that if one expression is numeric and the other is a string, then the numeric expression is less than the string expression. On the other hand, both `file.FileSize` and `file.lastModified` are strings although on the face of it:

- the `FileSize` property represents the size of the file (in bytes, `UIint64`) and
- the `LastModified` property is a datetime value indicating the time the file was last modified (see [CIM_datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx)).

To substitute missing debugging tool, there is involved basic debugging report in next commented script, see `strResult` variable.

```
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0

Dim strResult     '' debug output variable
Dim iFileAge, dFileDate, iByLarge, booIsOld, booIsBig, iiAll, iiBig, iiOld, iiLaa
Dim strComputer, wmi, files, objSWbemDateTime
iiAll = 0: iiBig = 0: iiOld = 0: iiLaa = 0: strComputer = "."
Dim objFile,iDaysOld,item,objFSO,dateTime,Filesize,LargeFile,strCheckDate
Dim FileName,FileName1,Logs,GetFile,file,filemodified,OldFile,LargeFile1

                    '' narrow output to reasonable extent for debugging
iDaysOld = 500      '' change to match your cimcurstances: iDaysOld = 180
iByLarge = 3600000  ''                              detto: iByLarge = 104857600

'' build debug output header (two lines):
strResult = vbNewLine & Now _
          & ToStr( "", 6) & ToStr( iDaysOld,  5) _
          & ToStr( "", 6) & ToStr( iByLarge, 12) & " " & Wscript.ScriptFullName
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & ToStr( "date", 10) & ToStr( "time", 9) _
          & ToStr( "old?", 6) & ToStr(  "days",  5) _
          & ToStr( "big?", 6) & ToStr( "bytes", 12) & " file full path" & vbNewLine

Set objSWbemDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set files = wmi.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension='log' AND Drive='c:'")
For Each file in files
  'If LCase(Right(Cstr(file.Name), 3)) = "log" Then
    iiAll = iiAll + 1
    FileSize  = CLng(file.FileSize)                '' cast string as numeric
    objSWbemDateTime.Value = file.lastModified
    dFileDate = objSWbemDateTime.GetVarDate(True)  '' convert CIM_datetime string to date
    iFileAge  = DateDiff("d", dFileDate, Now)      '' get file age in days
    booIsOld  = (iFileAge >  iDaysOld) 
    booIsBig  = (Filesize >= iByLarge)
    If booIsOld Then 
      OldFile   = (file.Name & "," & OldFile)
      iiOld = iiOld + 1
    End If 
    If booIsBig Then
      LargeFile = (file.Name & "," & LargeFile)
      iiBig = iiBig + 1
    End If
    If (booIsOld or booIsBig) Then
      '' populate debug output variable
      strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & dFileDate _
        & ToStr( booIsOld, 6) & ToStr( iFileAge,  5) _
        & ToStr( booIsBig, 6) & ToStr( Filesize, 12) & " " & file.Name
      ''debug only'' & vbNewLine & TypeName(file.FileSize) & " " & file.FileSize
    End If
    If (booIsOld and booIsBig) Then
      iiLaa = iiLaa + 1
    End If
  'End If 
Next
' wscript.echo "tr_Oldlogfiles=" &OldFile
' wscript.echo "tr_Largelogfiles=" &LargeFile
'' recapitulation
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
  & " all=" & iiAll & " old=" & iiOld & " big="  & iiBig & " old&big=" & iiLaa 
Wscript.Echo strResult    '' make public debug output
Wscript.Quit

Function ToStr( xVariant, iLength)
    ToStr = Right( Space( iLength) & CStr( xVariant), iLength)
End Function
```

**Output**:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\36540447.vbs

11.04.2016 18:03:44        500           3600000 D:\VB_scripts\SO\36540447.vbs
      date     time  old? days  big?       bytes file full path

05.04.2016 08:02:14 False    6  True     3600646 c:\windows\debug\mrt.log
11.04.2016 08:38:01 False    0  True     6458674 c:\windows\logs\cbs\cbs.log
19.03.2016 12:25:47 False   23  True    19358289 c:\windows\logs\dism\dism.log
22.08.2013 16:45:24  True  963 False       12962 c:\windows\security\logs\scesetup.log
22.08.2013 15:25:30  True  963 False           0 c:\windows\system32\config\components.log
22.08.2013 15:25:30  True  963 False           0 c:\windows\system32\config\default.log
22.08.2013 15:25:30  True  963 False           0 c:\windows\system32\config\security.log
22.08.2013 15:25:30  True  963 False           0 c:\windows\system32\config\software.log
22.08.2013 15:25:30  True  963 False           0 c:\windows\system32\config\system.log
18.03.2014 17:07:02  True  755 False        5446 c:\windows\vmgcoinstall.log

 all=313 old=7 big=3 old&big=0

==>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added a little function to the solution of ***JosefZ*** to convert size :

```
' Function to format a number into typical size scales
Function FormatSize(iSize)
    Dim aLabel,i
   aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB")
   For i = 0 to 4
      If iSize > 1024 Then iSize = iSize / 1024 Else Exit For End If
   Next
   FormatSize = Round(iSize, 2) & " " & aLabel(i)
End Function
```

And into the script :

```
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0

Dim strResult     '' debug output variable
Dim iFileAge, dFileDate, iByLarge, booIsOld, booIsBig, iiAll, iiBig, iiOld, iiLaa
Dim strComputer, wmi, files, objSWbemDateTime,fso,ws,LogFile
iiAll = 0: iiBig = 0: iiOld = 0: iiLaa = 0: strComputer = "."
Dim objFile,iDaysOld,item,objFSO,dateTime,Filesize,LargeFile,strCheckDate
Dim FileName,FileName1,Logs,GetFile,file,filemodified,OldFile,LargeFile1

                    '' narrow output to reasonable extent for debugging
iDaysOld = 500      '' change to match your cimcurstances: iDaysOld = 180
iByLarge = FormatSize(3600000) ''                              detto: iByLarge = 104857600
'wscript.echo iByLarge
'' build debug output header (two lines):
strResult = vbNewLine & Now _
          & ToStr( "", 6) & vbTab & ToStr( iDaysOld,  5) _
          & vbTab & ToStr( "", 6) & vbTab & ToStr( iByLarge, 12) & vbTab & " " & Wscript.ScriptFullName
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & ToStr( "date", 10) & ToStr( "time", 9) _
          & vbTab & ToStr( "old ?", 6) & vbTab & ToStr(  "days",  5) _
          & vbTab & ToStr( "big?", 6) & vbTab & ToStr( "bytes", 12) & vbTab & " file full path" & vbNewLine

Set objSWbemDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set files = wmi.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension='log' AND Drive='c:'")
For Each file in files
  'If LCase(Right(Cstr(file.Name), 3)) = "log" Then
    iiAll = iiAll + 1
    FileSize  = FormatSize(file.FileSize)                '' cast string as numeric
    objSWbemDateTime.Value = file.lastModified
    dFileDate = objSWbemDateTime.GetVarDate(True)  '' convert CIM_datetime string to date
    iFileAge  = DateDiff("d", dFileDate, Now)      '' get file age in days
    booIsOld  = (iFileAge >  iDaysOld) 
    booIsBig  = (Filesize >= iByLarge)
    If booIsOld Then 
      OldFile   = (file.Name & "," & OldFile)
      iiOld = iiOld + 1
    End If 
    If booIsBig Then
      LargeFile = (file.Name & "," & LargeFile)
      iiBig = iiBig + 1
    End If
    If (booIsOld or booIsBig) Then
      '' populate debug output variable
      strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & dFileDate _
        & ToStr( booIsOld, 6) & vbTab & iFileAge _
        & ToStr( booIsBig, 6) & vbTab & Filesize & "   " & file.Name
      ''debug only'' & vbNewLine & TypeName(file.FileSize) & " " & file.FileSize
    End If
    If (booIsOld and booIsBig) Then
      iiLaa = iiLaa + 1
    End If
  'End If 
Next
' wscript.echo "tr_Oldlogfiles=" &OldFile
' wscript.echo "tr_Largelogfiles=" &LargeFile
'' recapitulation
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
  & " all=" & iiAll & vbTab & " old=" & iiOld & vbTab & " big="  & iiBig & vbTab & " old&big=" & iiLaa 
Wscript.Echo strResult    '' make public debug output
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
If fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then
    fso.DeleteFile(LogFile)
End If
Call WriteLog(strResult,LogFile)
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
ws.run "Notepad "& LogFile
Wscript.Quit
'******************************************************************
Function ToStr( xVariant, iLength)
    ToStr = Right( Space( iLength) & CStr( xVariant), iLength)
End Function
'******************************************************************
' Function to format a number into typical size scales
Function FormatSize(iSize)
    Dim aLabel,i
   aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB")
   For i = 0 to 4
      If iSize > 1024 Then iSize = iSize / 1024 Else Exit For End If
   Next
   FormatSize = Round(iSize, 2) & " " & aLabel(i)
End Function
'******************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fso,ts 
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True,-1)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*****************************************************************
```